# List 1 updates List 2, then should trigger workflow on List 2

Tags: list, workflow

I set up a workflow to update List 2 when List 1 is edited. Now I want this update to trigger a workflow.

Apparently SharePoint does not treat an automatic (i.e. not user driven) update of List 2 as being an "edit" trigger for the workflow.

**How else can I trigger the workflow?**

I have been able to attach the workflow to List 1 and just have it pause 1 minute before checking the values of List 2 so List 2 has time to update. This works but will be impossible to implement since I actually have multiple lists updating List 2. I don't want to run the same workflow on every single one, especially since additional lists may be created in the future. Maintenance would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 and newer version won't let you run the workflow on the list 2 items if the item in list 2 is created/ modified using workflow. This is called 'Workflow recursion prevention'. However, you can use REST API to trigger this workflow.

Here is the reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2/

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Ok, I just read through it. Unfortunately, the workaround involves making extensive changes to Workflow 1 (the workflow associated with List 1). This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, since I'm going to have multiple lists with workflows just like Workflow 1. Am I misunderstanding the workaround? I'll still try it, but I was hoping for a more elegant and maintainable solution.